# Find correlated attributes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `Attributes` that contains bags of attribute name and values for items identified with an `ItemId`.

```
╔════════╦═══════╦══════════╗
║ ItemId ║ Name  ║  Value   ║
╠════════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║      1 ║ color ║ green    ║
║      1 ║ mood  ║ happy    ║
║      1 ║ age   ║ 5        ║
║      1 ║ type  ║ A        ║
║      2 ║ color ║ blue     ║
║      2 ║ mood  ║ sad      ║
║      2 ║ age   ║ 5        ║
║      2 ║ type  ║ B        ║
║      3 ║ color ║ red      ║
║      3 ║ mood  ║ angry    ║
║      3 ║ age   ║ 5        ║
║      3 ║ type  ║ B        ║
║      4 ║ color ║ yellow   ║
║      4 ║ mood  ║ whatever ║
║      4 ║ age   ║ 7        ║
║      5 ║ color ║ green    ║
║      5 ║ mood  ║ happy    ║
║      5 ║ age   ║ 2        ║
║      5 ║ type  ║ D        ║
╚════════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

Here's an SQLFiddle with the above structure and data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/08c4b/1

I would like to get a list of groups of attribute names that vary together.
The combination `ItemId` + `Name` is unique (there cannot be multiple values for the same attribute for the same item).

In the example above, such a group would be `color + mood`, because the following are always true:

- when the color is `green`, the mood is `happy`
- when the color is `red`, the mood is `angry`
- when the color is `blue`, the mood is `sad`
- when the color is `yellow`, the mood is `whatever`

If, for example, there was an extra item that had the color `red` and the mood `happy`, that would invalidate the above correlation.

Also, in this data set:

- age is not correlated with type, because:

  - item 1 has age `5` and type `A`
  - item 2 also has age `5`, but has type `B`
- color is not correlated with type, because:

  - item 1 is `green` and has type `A`
  - item 5 is also `green`, but has type `D`
- and so on...

Is it possible to write SQL statements that automatically discover these correlations between attributes?

Comment: I suggest to start with transposing rows to columns, for example using `crosstab` and then simply `SELECT corr(column1, column2) FROM ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible. One, likely not the simplest, way to do it would be something like this.

```
with pairs as (
 select l.*, r.name as name2, r.value as value2
 from Attribute l join Attribute r on l.ItemId = r.ItemId and l.name < r.name),
counts as (
 select name,name2,count(distinct value2)
 from pairs l join pairs r using (name,value,name2,value2)
 where l.itemid <= r.itemid group by name,value,name2)
select name,name2 from counts group by name, name2 having max(count)=1;
```

This version assumes that missing attributes correlate with everything, which may or may not be what's intended.

Comment: Thank you! I had to [quote some fields](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/08c4b/61), but otherwise the query works perfectly. I love the `l`/`r` naming convention for pairs (I usually do `a1`/`a2`). Also, I did not know about `USING`. That's awesome!

Answer (score 0):

while waiting for an answer I came up with a solution of my own and decided to post it here, although [Michał's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47176487/390819) seems better (more concise and possibly more efficient):

```
with associations as (
  -- associations of 
  select
    a1."ItemId" as Id1,
    a2."ItemId" as Id2,
    a1."Name" as Name,
    a1."Value" as Value1,
    a2."Value" as Value2  
  from Attribute a1
  join Attribute a2
    on  a1."ItemId" < a2."ItemId"
    and a1."Name"   = a2."Name"
),
names as (
  select distinct "Name"
  from Attribute
)
select *
from names n1
join names n2
  on n1."Name" < n2."Name"
  and not exists (
    -- try to find a miscorrelation
    select *
    from associations s1
    join associations s2
      on  s1.Id1 = s2.Id1
      and s1.Id2 = s2.Id2
      and s1.name in (n1."Name", n2."Name")
      and s2.name in (n1."Name", n2."Name")
      and s1.value1 = s1.value2
      and s2.value1 != s2.value2
  )
;
```

SQLFiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/08c4b/32